# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.settings' when trying to host application with wsgi server

Tags: python, django, wsgi, cherrypy, django-wsgi

So I wanted to deploy my first django application on a cherryPy webserver using wsgi. And I have issues with os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']. When trying to run application callable it throws error, that module is not found. Project structure:

```
ResourceManager
   ResourceManager
     ResourceManager
        __init__.py
        cherryserver.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
  SimpleResourceManager
    migrations
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    serializers.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  manage.py
```

wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.insert(0,BASE_DIR)
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ResourceManager.settings'
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ResourceManager.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

cherryserver.py:

```
import cherrypy
from ResourceManager.ResourceManager.wsgi import application


if __name__ == '__main__':
# Mount the application
cherrypy.tree.graft(application, "/")

# Unsubscribe the default server
cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()


 # Instantiate a new server object
server = cherrypy._cpserver.Server()

 # Configure the server object
server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
server.socket_port = 8080
server.thread_pool = 30

# Subscribe this server
server.subscribe()

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

Application works fine when using command runserver 8080, but when i tried to run it on different server. It says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "ResourceManager.settings".

So i tried: Change where cherryserver.py is located in directory, I have added additional lines of code to wsgy.py file and I'm running out of ideas what is wrong when I'm deploying my app on different server. Why I'm using cherryPy, well I have to test 5 web servers that are based on python.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing from:

```
from ResourceManager.ResourceManager.wsgi import application
```

To:

```
from wsgi.py import application
```

This is because they are located in the same directory, if this does not work just mess around with the from as it seems that your path to the wsgi file is wrong.